# How to replicate Lynda.com transitions in my own presentations (Keynote preferred, Powerpoint possible)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, iwork-keynote

I recently noticed that lynda.com uses in their training videos a very interesting transition that I would like to replicate in my own presentations.

They are somewhat similar to the computer screen animations in the "Minority Report" movie: they zoom out to a huge sheet, pan, and zoom back in to a new location.

It's very good for navigating deep hierarchies. For example when you are at level 1, you can see level 3, but it's tiny and unreadable. You then transition by zooming in to a deeper level that suddenly becomes legible.

I can imagine also to use it using a large "mind map" as a common Ariane thread, to dive into details (and back out) while still taking advantage of the visual memory of the audience.

It a bit difficult to describe, I hope I managed to convey the idea. You can see them in action for example there (iPhone programming training):

http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourse.aspx?lpk2=48369

Then click on "What you should know" in the introduction chapter.

See for example in that movie between 22s and 24s, then between 27s and 28s.

How do they do that? How could I replicate that effect?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was told the software they use, it's Prezi

http://prezi.com/

If anybody has an idea how to do something similar within Keynote...

Answer (score 2):

At least some of training on [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/) was created from [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html). Over the past year, I've been using [pptPlex](http://www.officelabs.com/projects/pptPlex/Pages/default.aspx), and it is amazing.